# Cannot resolve method getApplicationContext - ImageButton in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I have got a Navigation Drawer with Fragments, and this is the code of one of them:

```
import ...
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;


public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {
    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    View rootView;
    public ImageButton add;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        ListView lista = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lista);
        String[] lista_nazwisk = {"Krzysztof Podobiński", "Bartłomiej Zakrzewski", "Kamil Wirtek"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lista_nazwisk);
        lista.setAdapter(adapter);

        add = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.add_button);
        add.setOnClickListener(this);

        return rootView;

    }
       @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {

          }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }


}
```

But when I'm trying to add on-click action in OnClick class the following:

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Blah blah", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Android Studio screams it can't be like that because of "Cannot resolve method getApplicationContext"

What should I do?

Comment: Use `getActivity()` or `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` because `getApplicationContext()` not available in Fragment

Comment: Or you can create app class and inside onCreate method set application context in static field. After it you can use it via AppClass.getContext() where getContext() is static getter which returns context field